# How to create a VBA Code that deletes the row if the E cell in the Sheet1 is blank or the value exists in the A cell of Sheet2

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I am trying to create a VBA code that loops through the E cells in the Sheet1.

- If the E cell is empty, delete the whole row.
- If the value of E cell exists in the Column A of Sheet 2, delete the whole row.
- If none of the above mentioned condition is met, do nothing.

The below code that I did, deletes the rows where the E call is empty, but it does not delete the rows where the value of E cell exists in the Column A of Sheet 2.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet
    Dim s2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowS1 As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim found As Boolean
    
    'Set worksheet objects
    Set s1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    'Get last row of Sheet1
    lastRowS1 = s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Loop through rows in Sheet1
    For i = lastRowS1 To 1 Step -1
        str = s1.Cells(i, "E").Value
        
        'Check if value exists in Sheet2 column A
        found = False
        For j = 1 To s2.Cells(s2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If str = s2.Cells(j, "A").Value Then
                found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        
        'If value not found or cell is blank, delete entire row
        If Not found Or str = "" Then
            s1.Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
    
    'Display message when done
    MsgBox "Done deleting rows."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the below section.

Initially you said if the value is available in sheet2, you need to delete... But you condition mentions as "**Not**" found, which is incorrect

```
'If value not found or cell is blank, delete entire row
    If found Or str = "" Then
        s1.Rows(i).Delete
    End If
```

Additionally you can check if str = "" before hand so that you can skip the "checking" loop if its true.  Saves time.

Comment: Another option to speed up is to replace the inner loop with `Find` or `Application.Match` or `Application.CountIfs`.

Comment: I have tried that, but when I remove "Not", it deletes everything on the sheet.